# Create hierarchy from flat list using map/reduce

Tags: mapreduce, couchdb

Suppose I had a Couch instance full of documents like the following:

```
{"id":"1","parent":null},
{"id":"2","parent":"1"},
{"id":"3","parent":"1"},
{"id":"4","parent":"3"},
{"id":"5","parent":"null"},
{"id":"6","parent":"5"}
```

Is there a way using MapReduce to build a view that would return my documents in this format:

```
{
  "id":"1",
  "children": [
    {"id":"2"},
    {"id":"3","children":[
      {"id":"4"}
    ]}
  ]
},
{
  "id":"5",
  "children": [ {"id":"6"} ]
}
```

My instinct says "no" because I imagine you'd need one pass for each level of the hierarchy, and items can be nested indefinitely deep.

Answer (score 0):

By using only `map` function this can not be achieved, yes. But the `reduce` will have access to the whole list of documents emitted by the `map` functions: http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Introduction_to_CouchDB_views#Reduce_Functions

To implement that, you will need a robust reduce function, that should also be abled to use "rereduce" efficiently.

In the end, it might be easier to create a view, that will map each document by its parent as key. Example:

```
function(doc) {
  emit(doc.parent, doc._id);
}
```

This view will allow to query the top level documents with the key "null" and with sub ids like "1", "3" or "5".
A reduce function could added to create a result like this:

```
null => [1, 5]
1 => [2, 3]
3 => [4]
5 => [6]
```

The structural tree you whished for is contained therein in a different format and can be created out there.